# intellij wrap and sign

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

What's the setting I need to change in my IntelliJ (Android Studio) IDE to make formatting change this line:

```
return Objects.equal(this.city, other.city) && Objects.equal(this.state, other.state) && Objects.equal(this.country, other.country) && Objects.equal(this.location, other.location) && Objects.equal(this.streetAddress1, other.streetAddress1) && Objects.equal(this.streetAddress2, other.streetAddress2) && Objects.equal(this.postalCode, other.postalCode);
```

to look like this:

```
return Objects.equal(this.city, other.city) &&
       Objects.equal(this.state, other.state) &&
       Objects.equal(this.country, other.country) &&
       Objects.equal(this.location, other.location) &&
       Objects.equal(this.streetAddress1, other.streetAddress1) &&
       Objects.equal(this.streetAddress2, other.streetAddress2) &&
       Objects.equal(this.postalCode, other.postalCode);
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with your preferred right margin and line-wrapping, but it's been a while since I used IntelliJ.

Comment: there are so many settings in the wrapping menu that I can't find the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible:

1. Go to `Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces [tab] ->
   Binary Expressions [tree node]`
2. Set `Binary Expressions` to `Chop down if long`
3. Check the `Align when multiline`

I have also had success on teams using mixed IDE's with JIndent.  Although commercial its more powerful and is IDE and build agnostic.